# Convert a HTML page into a mountain

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, parsing

**Task:** convert a HTML page into a mountain!

When HTML pages are indented, they can look like:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But to be honest, a mountain is more representative of this structure.

So we can rewrite it as:

```
     /\
  /\/  \
 /      \
/        \
```

The outermost slashes on the left and right correspond to the outer div - each pair of HTML tags should be represented as `/` for the starting tag and `\` for the ending tag - inside all tags are "higher", with the same structure.

**Input:**

- There will be no `<!DOCTYPE>`
- There will be no self-closing tags e.g. `<img />` or `<br />`
- There may be attributes or content inside the tags
- There may be spaces or tabs - your program should ignore these
- There will be no spaces between `<` or `</` and the tag name
- All input will be valid HTML

**Output** - a mountain representing the tags as above.

*More testcases:*

Input:

```
<div id="123"> HI </div><a><span></span></a>
```

Output:

```
   /\
/\/  \
```

Input:

```
<body id="<"></body>
```

Output:

```
/\
```

Comment: A word of [caution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2586922) for golfers...

Comment: Will there ever be `</ div>`? or can we assume the slash is always adjacent to the `div`

Comment: hmmm, I'll be nice - you can assume no spaces after `<` or `</` (until the tag name) - however there may still be spaces for attributes e.g. `<div id="aDiv">`

Comment: Perhaps this could use a few more test cases?

Comment: Can we assume the document would be valid? (i.e. every starting tag has a valid ending one, and the order of the tags is nested properly)

Comment: @Uriel yes, of course.

Comment: Can to-be-ignored text appear before and after the first tag in the document?

Comment: No, this will not appear.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarifications

Comment: Will there ever be any case where there is a poorly written page with incomplete tags such as `<div`?

Comment: This really needs more test cases, and an *exact* description (in BNF, say) of what the input will look like. I don’t know what "Valid HTML" means exactly, and how many edge cases I should support. (First one that comes to mind: space between the tag name and `>` such as `<a >b</a >`.)

Comment: For what it’s worth I think the challenge is interesting enough focusing only on strings like `<body><a>xxx</a>yyy<section><div>zzz</div></section></body>`. No attributes, only simple matched tags and lowercase letters as text content. HTML is very complex.

Comment: I feel like this challenge has turned into an excuse to get people to use JavaScript for golfing. :) though if everyone thinks this is too restrictive, I'll change the question.

Comment: I call dibs on GNU sed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## HTML + CSS + JavaScript, 39 + 141 + 20 = 200 bytes

Outputs visually to the webpage. To allow this to work with special elements like `<body>`, all letters in the input are replaced.

```js
p.innerHTML=prompt().replace(/\w/g,'a')
```

```css
#p,#p *{display:flex;padding:0 0 1rem;align-items:flex-end;font-size:0}#p :before,#p :after{content:'/';font-size:1rem}#p :after{content:'\\'
```

```html
<pre id=p>
```

---

## HTML + CSS + JavaScript, 10 + 103 + 20 = 133 bytes

Solution that works if there is no content within tags.

```js
p.innerHTML=prompt()
```

```css
#p,#p *{display:flex;padding:0 0 1em;align-items:flex-end}#p :before{content:'/'}#p :after{content:'\\'
```

```html
<pre id=p>
```

Comment: This is really clever!

Comment: I've never seen golfed CSS before :)

Comment: This fails both of the test cases.

Comment: @Giuseppe I think you may be able to fix it with display = none on all elements and using an iframe instead of a <pre>

Comment: @Giuseppe Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript + JQuery, <s>275</s> 246 bytes

Saved 29 bytes thanks to [Rick Hitchcock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42260/rick-hitchcock)

```js
j=(a,b,c,i)=>{s=(c=' '.repeat(b))+'/\n';for(i=0;V=a.children[i];i++){s=s+j(V,b+1)}return s+c+'\\\n';};f=s=>{s=j($(s)[0],0).split`
`;w=Math.max.apply(0,s.map(a=>a.length));o='';for(i=w-1;i>=0;i--){for(c=0;C=s[c];c++){o+=C[i]||' '}o+='\n'}alert(o)}
```

A pretty Naïve solution to the problem. Parses the HTML with JQuery's `$(string)`, then recursively builds a sideways mountain with the format:

```
/
 /
  children...
 \
\
```

Then rotates the resulting string counterclockwise, and alerts the result.

```js
    j=(a,b,c,i)=>{s=(c=' '.repeat(b))+'/\n';for(i=0;V=a.children[i];i++){s=s+j(V,b+1)}return s+c+'\\\n';};f=s=>{s=j($(s)[0],0).split`
`;w=Math.max.apply(0,s.map(a=>a.length));o='';for(i=w-1;i>=0;i--){for(c=0;C=s[c];c++){o+=C[i]||' '}o+='\n'}return o}

update=_=>outp.textContent=f(inp.value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id=inp oninput=update()></textarea>
<pre id=outp></pre>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's naïve and not naÃ¯ve? (I can stop this joke if you want)

Comment: 269 bytes by changing to: `j=(a,b,c,i)=>{s=(c=' '.repeat(b))+'/\n';for(i` ...

Comment: Change to `for(c=0;c<s.length;c++)` to `for(c=0;s[c];c++)`

Comment: Similarly, change `for(i=0;i<a.children.length;i++)` to `for(i=0;a.children[i];i++)`

Answer (score 3):

## HTML + JavaScript (ES6), 8 + 192 = 200 bytes

#### JS

```
s=>[...(E.innerHTML=s,y=0,o=[],m=n=>1+[...n.children].map(m).join``+0)(E.firstChild)].map((c,x,a)=>{(o[y+=+c]||(o[y]=[...a].fill` `))[x]=`\\/`[c],y+=~-c})&&o.reverse().map(l=>l.join``).join`
`
```

#### HTML

```
<a id=E>
```

```js
f=

s=>[...(E.innerHTML=s,y=0,o=[],m=n=>1+[...n.children].map(m).join``+0)(E.firstChild)].map((c,x,a)=>{(o[y+=+c]||(o[y]=[...a].fill` `))[x]=`\\/`[c],y+=~-c})&&o.reverse().map(l=>l.join``).join`
`

console.log(f(`<div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`))
```

```html
<a id=E>
```

### Less golfed

```
s=>{
    E.innerHTML=s,
    y=0,
    o=[],
    m=n=>1+[...n.children].map(m).join``+0,
    [...m(E.firstChild)].map((c,x,a)=>{
        y+=+c
        if(!o[y]) o[y]=[...a].fill` `
        o[y][x]=`\\/`[c]
        y+=~-c
    })
    return o.reverse().map(l=>l.join``).join`\n`
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the byte count include the `id=E` HTML element since you are relying on it for the code to work?

Comment: @Birjolaxew Whoops! I missed that somehow.

Comment: HTML has built-in HTML parser... creative solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>38</s> <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
¶¡εDð¢4÷s'/å_„\/sèú}ζR»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0LZDC89tdTm84dAik8Pbi9X1Dy@Nf9QwL0a/@PCKw7tqz20LOrT7/38lJSWblMwyOy4FIECwsPD08UjiENHHZQKUCaGATgAA)

---

I am still golfing this. It assumes that in HTML you will always use 4 spaces for indentation, and does not work on "non-pretty" HTML. Not sure how to handle the "content" part, if this is invalid please edit the question to show an example with a node that has content.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
≔¹ηＦ⮌θ«≡ι"≦¬η<Ｆη¿⁼ζ/←¶\↙/≔ιζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3LCsIwEEXXyVcMs0qhUqo7jQFBQUFFXHcTamoDJX2ktlDx22OsWc3MfZzJS9nltayc21mrn4alMZTRhhZ1B@yuBtVZxdoogjcldtR9XgLT85VLqwAzxDUl5CKb0L/W/Z8QAnz2Z1wZ@Y3oAtihfcnKsikGTNDDb502PVufVeHLmJkswx@BEFV5RnD39WhCIpntDyXhqY5h8srHOf7QA@jHFtPlCgUcT8ATLwkuBbeNNIInYUhB3WKovg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔¹η
```

The `h` variable is used to keep track of whether we are inside quotes.

```
Ｆ⮌θ«
```

Loop over the string in reverse order.

```
≡ι
```

Switch on the currenc character.

```
"≦¬η
```

If it's a `"` then toggle the quote flag.

```
<Ｆη
```

If it's a `<` and we're not inside quotes, then...

```
¿⁼ζ/
```

If the next character (previous in the loop because we're looping in reverse) is a `/`, then...

```
←¶\
```

Move up and draw a `\` leftwards, else...

```
↙/
```

Draw a `/` and move down and left.

```
≔ιζ
```

Remember the character for the next loop iteration.